# Docker Autobuild failing with "[Errno 28] No space left on device"

Tags: docker, pytorch

I am building a docker image which does some object detection on yolov7 and up until recently it has been working perfectly

Then one day I logged into docker hub just to check the status of a build of one of my images and I saw that my builds have all started failing.When I have a look at the logs this is what I get:
`ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 28] No space left on device: '/tmp/pip-unpacked-wheel-r3egz0yp/torch/lib/libtorch_cuda_cpp.so' -> '/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/torch/lib/libtorch_cuda_cpp.so'`

I can build this exact image just fine locally but the autobuild just does not work.

Any suggestions?

Here is the build log: (I have removed the previous logs as there were no issues up to this point)

```
2022-12-14T08:38:58Z #14 [ 8/10] RUN pip install torch==1.11.0+cu113 torchvision==0.12.0+cu113 torchaudio==0.11.0 --extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu113
2022-12-14T08:38:59Z #14 1.429 Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu113
2022-12-14T08:38:59Z #14 1.701 Collecting torch==1.11.0+cu113
2022-12-14T08:38:59Z #14 1.707 Downloading https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu113/torch-1.11.0%2Bcu113-cp38-cp38-linux_x86_64.whl (1637.0 MB)
2022-12-14T08:40:08Z #14 70.63 Collecting torchvision==0.12.0+cu113
2022-12-14T08:40:08Z #14 70.65 Downloading https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu113/torchvision-0.12.0%2Bcu113-cp38-cp38-linux_x86_64.whl (22.3 MB)
2022-12-14T08:40:10Z #14 72.18 Collecting torchaudio==0.11.0
2022-12-14T08:40:10Z #14 72.19 Downloading https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu113/torchaudio-0.11.0%2Bcu113-cp38-cp38-linux_x86_64.whl (2.9 MB)
2022-12-14T08:40:10Z #14 72.38 Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from torch==1.11.0+cu113) (3.10.0.2)
2022-12-14T08:40:10Z #14 72.39 Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from torchvision==0.12.0+cu113) (1.21.2)
2022-12-14T08:40:10Z #14 72.40 Requirement already satisfied: requests in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from torchvision==0.12.0+cu113) (2.26.0)
2022-12-14T08:40:10Z #14 72.42 Requirement already satisfied: pillow!=8.3.*,>=5.3.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from torchvision==0.12.0+cu113) (9.2.0)
2022-12-14T08:40:10Z #14 72.44 Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from requests->torchvision==0.12.0+cu113) (1.26.7)
2022-12-14T08:40:10Z #14 72.46 Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from requests->torchvision==0.12.0+cu113) (2021.10.8)
2022-12-14T08:40:10Z #14 72.46 Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer~=2.0.0; python_version >= "3" in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from requests->torchvision==0.12.0+cu113) (2.0.7)
2022-12-14T08:40:10Z #14 72.47 Requirement already satisfied: idna<4,>=2.5; python_version >= "3" in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from requests->torchvision==0.12.0+cu113) (3.3)
2022-12-14T08:40:12Z #14 73.91 Installing collected packages: torch, torchvision, torchaudio
2022-12-14T08:40:12Z #14 73.91 Attempting uninstall: torch
2022-12-14T08:40:12Z #14 73.91 Found existing installation: torch 1.13.0
2022-12-14T08:40:18Z #14 79.92 Uninstalling torch-1.13.0:
2022-12-14T08:40:50Z #14 112.3 Successfully uninstalled torch-1.13.0
2022-12-14T08:41:35Z #14 157.6 Rolling back uninstall of torch
2022-12-14T08:41:35Z #14 157.6 Moving to /usr/local/bin/convert-caffe2-to-onnx
2022-12-14T08:41:35Z #14 157.6 from /tmp/pip-uninstall-21vj9ta9/convert-caffe2-to-onnx
2022-12-14T08:41:35Z #14 157.6 Moving to /usr/local/bin/convert-onnx-to-caffe2
2022-12-14T08:41:35Z #14 157.6 from /tmp/pip-uninstall-21vj9ta9/convert-onnx-to-caffe2
2022-12-14T08:41:35Z #14 157.6 Moving to /usr/local/bin/torchrun
2022-12-14T08:41:35Z #14 157.6 from /tmp/pip-uninstall-21vj9ta9/torchrun
2022-12-14T08:41:35Z #14 157.6 Moving to /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/functorch/
2022-12-14T08:41:35Z #14 157.6 from /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/~unctorch
2022-12-14T08:41:35Z #14 157.6 Moving to /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/torch-1.13.0.dist-info/
2022-12-14T08:41:35Z #14 157.6 from /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/~orch-1.13.0.dist-info
2022-12-14T08:41:35Z #14 157.6 Moving to /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/torch/
2022-12-14T08:41:35Z #14 157.6 from /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/~orch
2022-12-14T08:41:35Z #14 157.6 Moving to /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/torchgen/
2022-12-14T08:41:35Z #14 157.6 from /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/~orchgen
2022-12-14T08:41:36Z #14 158.1 ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 28] No space left on device: '/tmp/pip-unpacked-wheel-bkn_wblz/torch/lib/libtorch_cuda_cpp.so' -> '/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/torch/lib/libtorch_cuda_cpp.so'
2022-12-14T08:41:36Z #14 158.1
2022-12-14T08:41:36Z #14 ERROR: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c pip install torch==1.11.0+cu113 torchvision==0.12.0+cu113 torchaudio==0.11.0 --extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu113]: exit code: 1
2022-12-14T08:41:36Z ------
2022-12-14T08:41:36Z > [ 8/10] RUN pip install torch==1.11.0+cu113 torchvision==0.12.0+cu113 torchaudio==0.11.0 --extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu113:
2022-12-14T08:41:36Z #14 157.6 Moving to /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/functorch/
2022-12-14T08:41:36Z #14 157.6 from /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/~unctorch
2022-12-14T08:41:36Z #14 157.6 Moving to /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/torch-1.13.0.dist-info/
2022-12-14T08:41:36Z #14 157.6 from /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/~orch-1.13.0.dist-info
2022-12-14T08:41:36Z #14 157.6 Moving to /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/torch/
2022-12-14T08:41:36Z #14 157.6 from /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/~orch
2022-12-14T08:41:36Z #14 157.6 Moving to /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/torchgen/
2022-12-14T08:41:36Z #14 157.6 from /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/~orchgen
2022-12-14T08:41:36Z #14 158.1 ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 28] No space left on device: '/tmp/pip-unpacked-wheel-bkn_wblz/torch/lib/libtorch_cuda_cpp.so' -> '/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/torch/lib/libtorch_cuda_cpp.so'
2022-12-14T08:41:36Z #14 158.1
2022-12-14T08:41:36Z ------
2022-12-14T08:41:36Z ERROR: failed to solve: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c pip install torch==1.11.0+cu113 torchvision==0.12.0+cu113 torchaudio==0.11.0 --extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu113]: exit code: 1
2022-12-14T08:41:36Z Build failed using Buildkit (1)
```

Comment: Possibly related: https://github.com/docker/hub-feedback/issues/2209

Comment: give it more space then

Comment: How @ChristophRackwitz? I never set a size limitation

Comment: perhaps investigate "docker no space left on device" as a research question. [tour], [ask], [mre]